# Wix Custom Dialog Validation

Tags: validation, wix

How can you validate fields in a Wix Custom Dialog? I've got a combo box that I'm using to set a property that cannot be null.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's going to depend on the complexity of your validation.  For a simple one control must have a value you could do something like:

```
<UI...>
 <Dialog...>
  <Control Id="Next"...>  
   <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="ErrorsDlg">Not SomeProperty</Publish>
   <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="NextDialog">Property</Publish>
  </Control>
 </Dialog>
</UI>
```

Where ErrorsDlg is a Dialog that you create to resemble a MessageBox style dialog.  If you have more complicated validation you can write a custom action that reads properties, evaluates rules and sets a flag along with an error message to be displayed.  That would look more like this:

```
<UI...>
 <Dialog...>
  <Control Id="Next"...>  
   <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="ValidateCA">1</Publish>
   <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="ErrorsDlg">Not DataValid</Publish>
   <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="NextDialog">DataValid</Publish>
  </Control>
 </Dialog>
</UI>
```